# How to I upload a text based file to Artifactory so it doesn't add the html-header?

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to upload a script (sh/perl/python/etc) using:

```html
curl -i -u<username:password> -T file.sh "http://my.server/directory"
```

and the resultant file in Artifactory has a header of:

```html
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Artifactory/4.2.0
X-Artifactory-Id: 8e3d0483423c1418:-6b134231:162ec3535a99:-8000
Last-Modified: Tue, 08 May 2018 16:54:33 GMT
ETag: a903f23377d76670a1ea646cfaeae8793ba0f975
X-Checksum-Sha1: a903f23377d764470a1ea646cfaeae4f93ba0f975
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Checksum-Md5: a6b42e04c9a849772975a46b05718748
X-Artifactory-Filename: file.txt
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.sh"; filename*=UTF-8''file.sh
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 22982
Date: Tue, 08 May 2018 16:54:51 GMT
```

So when I get the script and try to execute it I get an error.  Is there a configuration in Artifactory somewhere that stops this change to text based files?

Comment: "So when I get the script and try to execute it I get an error." How are you getting the script, and what's the error it gives you?

Comment: I'm using curl with the -O option.  The error depends on the file.  This same header is getting added to my bash scripts and python scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't expect there's anything wrong with the file upload, and I don't expect the headers exist in the file inside Artifactory. I think the issue occurs when you download the file.

Your problem appears to be that `curl` is printing the headers to `stdout` before printing the file contents, so they all appear in the downloaded file. To avoid this, do not pass `-i` when downloading the file. If you need to see the headers, you can pass `-v`, which will print the headers (and other information) to `stderr`, meaning it will be written to the screen instead of the file.